# IIS URL Rewrite Default Language Path

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a rule working whereby the language identifier is in the url path.  We want to force the url to the en version if a language is not specified.  For example:

www.domain.com/page.aspx should redirect to www.domain.com/en/page.aspx

Here's the rule we have so far, but it keeps ending up in a redirect loop.

```
<rule name="Default Language" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>                
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(en|es|ph)/" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/en/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Any ideas where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change your rule to:

```
<rule name="Default Language" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^en/" negate="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

It will check if the url starts with `en/` and if not, it will append `en/` in front of the requested path.

You had an infinite redirection because whatever back reference was sent to `/en/{R:1}`, it was matching `(.*)` (as it matches anything/everything).